# iOS 6 : Warning with linkers / Icon error

Tags: ios, testing, frameworks, icons

I'm finishing my first app', without warnings when building, and running correctly on my iphone.
I try to set an icon, in adding a picture 57x57 .png and 114x114 .png in the summary of my app, but it only appears on the simulator, not on my iphone ! I tried to go on the info.plist, but i didn't change anything :/
I've got one warning with this that i don't know how to fix :

"Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'iNiveau PRO/iNiveau PRO-Info.plist'."

Secondly, i tried to run for testing, and get 4 errors (they didn't appear when i just run on my iphone), i also don't know how to fix :

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_AVMediaTypeVideo",
>   referenced from:
>         -[NiveauViewController setTorchOn:] in NiveauViewController.o   "_CGAffineTransformMakeRotation", referenced from:
>         -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
>         -[NiveauViewController viewDidLoad] in NiveauViewController.o
>         -[LenkhoViewController viewDidLoad] in LenkhoViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in NiveauViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Because i saw it could be a problem with framekors, but i correctly add frameworks on my files like for example in NiveauViewController.h :
--> #import < AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h >

Thanks a lot ! =)

Comment: EDIT : There was a problem in the Tests application, with frameworks. But now it works ! Just need help for icons ! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually link your project to these frameworks. Click your project in the "Project Navigator" on the left side of Xcode, select your target, select the summary tab and then scroll down until you see the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" Section. Click the plus icon.

It looks like you need to add AVFoundation.framework and QuartzCore.framework.

[image]

Then as far as the icon dilemma goes, it's hard to say without more information, but have you verified that your icons are named "Icon.png" and "Icon@2x.png" and that they really are 57x57 and 114x114?

Comment: Roooh i can't post images to show you because i'm too new on stack... :/ But I think i correctly add libraries like you show, in the summary of my project and after. And for the icon, i put the images on the summary "app icons", they are really 57x57 and 114x114 and with "Icon.png" and "Icon@2x.png" names, it doesn't work, i don't know why... :/

Comment: Furthermore, you know at the center of your image you have "Project" and "Target". On Target, i have my application "iNiveau Pro", and "iNiveau ProTests". And both of them have the icon that i set, but not on my iphone. This is why i really don't understand :/

Answer (score 0):

Including framework headers is not enough. You should select your project target, choose summary, and add AVFoundation framework in section "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" for linking.

Comment: But I have already done this ! This i why i don't understand this sort of errors :/